# Can commoner be used as an adjective? I thought it was a noun. Can we say something is commoner?

Tags: word-choice

I thought "commoner" is 'a person not of royal birth', but saw "commoner" used instead of "more common".  Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

It can be used that way and understood, because of the general pattern of adding *-er* to adjectives to form comparatives. However, *commoner* as a comparative is not standard.

The Oxford English Dictionary's entry for *commoner* only lists it as a noun. [Wiktionary's entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/commoner#Adjective) does include an adjectival form, and it is defined as "more common," but calls this usage "less desirable" and "much less commonly used" than "more common."

Answer (score 2):

[It seems that it is allowed:](http://www.onestopenglish.com/grammar/grammar-reference/adjectives/comparative-and-superlative-adjectives-article/144846.article)

> As a general rule, most other two syllable adjectives also form comparatives and superlatives with more and most, apart from those ending in -y (see (iii) above). However a few two-syllable adjectives can take either -er/-est or more/most. Here are five of the most common examples:

```
 common          commoner/more common    the commonest/most common      
 narrow      narrower/more narrow        the narrowest/most narrow
```

Checking up Google Ngrams, using "commonest" and "most common" (not using "commoner" as Google Ngrams will show results of "commoner" as a noun) :

[image]

"Most common"(and deductively "more common") is more used.

Answer (score 0):

While Wiktionary (currently) [has that definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/commoner#Adjective), such [prescription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription) may not work well depending on your audience.

Take this sentence for example:

> Here's a commoner ball.

It's not a stretch to imagine the listener might hear it as *"Here's a commoner-ball"*  instead. "commoner" here refers to an [adjectival noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) instead of a comparative adjective.